# How can I classify time-series given a predictor for each of them?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, classification, predictive-models, predictor

Say that I have two time-series and a predictor for each of them. I would like to build a classifer that given a window of future (and unseen) samples returns which series is more likely to have produced them.

One vanilla approach could be to check which predictor provides the best prediction by applying both of them to each series and assessing how close the results are to the new samples. However, things get more complicated when the scores of the predictors are comparable.

In case the predictors are obtained by means of neural networks, is there a way to convert the two prediction models to a single classifier? Can we say anything about the confidence of this kind of classification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem. I would start with producing predictions of both series, the calculating correlation of the series observed with the series predicted.  Another version is to then regress the observed on both predicted series (not predictors themselves), and analyze the significance of the coefficients similar to [encompassing testing](https://www.economicsnetwork.ac.uk/showcase/cook_encompassing)

More advanced approach is instead of looking at just correlation to analyze cross correlation.

Comment: What do you mean by analyzing the crosscorrelation? Is it what you just described or something more?

Comment: cross correlation is the same as correlation but the series are lagged relative to each other. something like $corr[x_t,y_{t-\Delta t}]$, just in case the predicted and observed are lagged for some reason